# How to find memory consumption of a php script?

Tags: memory, php

I am running a php script as a process on a Linux shell. With different tools (top, xdebug, ...) I see the dynamic memory consumption (heap memory) of this very complex script continuously rising.

How can I find out exactly the line in the code or the variable or the place, that is causing this behavior? Where is the memory leak of the php script?

**Additional information:**

- Linux version 2.6.30-gentoo-r4
- PHP Version 5.2.10-pl0-gentoo
- I can modify the script
- I can use xdebug

Please give a reason for closing this question.

Comment: This is usually done via profiling. http://xdebug.org/docs/profiler

Comment: I tried running thre file with `xdebug`. All I got was a 60000 line long list of system calls and the corresponding memory consumption. This did not answer the question, where exactly the memory leak is.

Comment: php 5.2 doesn't have a garbage collector. *Every* time memory is allocated it's basically leaked, since it will never be reclaimed. 5.3 added a garbage collector.

Comment: Does it mean my question cannot be answered without looking by hand at all of these 60000 lines (and more)?

Comment: Please, a quick answer to the feasibility of finding the memory leak with php 5.2, before this question is closed! If people think this is not possible, it is at least some clarification. I also wonder, what is wrong with the question this time. Maybe superuser? stackoverflow? healthy eating?

Comment: The nature of debugging in most languages is that it is very tedious, unfortunately. If all you have to go is "my program uses a lot of memory", that's not necessarily a *leak*, it could just be poor structure.  So most likely you do need to look at what is going on in tedious detail and decide where your most serious problems form.  Finally, true leaks (due to lost references) in a language like php should be very unusual, except in cases where what jordanm said is true (no GC), in which case you are wasting your time trying to stop them.

Comment: @goldilocks: Thank you very much for your assessment of my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this at suspect areas

```
echo memory_get_usage();

// Suspect code here

echo memory_get_usage();
```